# How to plot a Circle Using geom_circle function

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

My goal is to draw the dimensions/lines of an NBA basketball court using a combination of the ggplot2 and ggforce packages. I have used the + geom_segment() layer to successfully draw the line segments (sidelines, free throw lines, etc.), but I am having a hard time using the + geom_circle() and + geom_arc() functions to draw the circles and circle arcs (three point line, half-court circle, etc.)

My code is as follows, where object 'sample' is simply a data frame of shots, with x and y coordinates:

```
ggplot(sample, aes(shot_x, shot_y)) +
geom_point(color = "red", alpha = .2) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 94, y = 0, yend = 0)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 94, y = 50, yend = 50)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = 50)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 94, xend = 94, y = 50, yend = 0)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 14, y = 3, yend = 3)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 80, xend = 94, y = 3, yend = 3)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 14, y = 47, yend = 47)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 80, xend = 94, y = 47, yend = 47)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 47, xend = 47, y = 0, yend = 50)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 19, y = 19, yend = 19)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 19, y = 31, yend = 31)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 75, xend = 94, y = 19, yend = 19)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 75, xend = 94, y = 31, yend = 31)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 19, xend = 19, y = 19, yend = 31)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 75, xend = 75, y = 19, yend = 31)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 4, xend = 4, y = 22, yend = 28)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 90, xend = 90, y = 22, yend = 28)) +
coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

When I add:

```
+ geom_circle(aes(x0 = 47, y0 = 25, r = 6))
```

(which should draw a circle at half-court), no circles appear on the visualization, and the result includes the initial graph (line segment and points for shots), along with a duplicate of all the data points, but offset up and to the right. To be clear, no errors occur, it's just that the result is not what I'm going for.

Also, when I remove the geom_point() layer entirely, and start the code like:

```
ggplot() +
geom_segment(...)
```

Then I can add the geom_circle() layer successfully. However, I need to be able to add the circle and also include the data points.

Any idea why this is happening, or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to help if we can't see what's going on. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you included data for `sample` then we could run the code to see what's happening.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why, but adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` inside the `geom_circle` call fixes it.

```
library(ggforce) # geom_circle used to be in ggplot2, now is in ggforce
sample = data.frame(shot_x = c(10, 20), shot_y = c(30, 40))
ggplot(sample, aes(shot_x, shot_y)) +
  # ... all your segment lines
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 47, y0 = 25, r = 6), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image: output]